# Sum of values in a column for all distinct values in another column in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
ID | Value | Person

1  | 10    | Roy
1  | 10    | Sam
1  | 10    | Willis
2  | 50    | Troy
2  | 50    | Loy
```

I want to get some of "Value" column for all distinct IDs. So in the above example, the result should be 60 (i.e., 10+ 50).

I tried doing `sum(value) over (partition by ID)` but that's not giving the desired result.

Please let me know how I can achieve this.

I'm trying to do this in PostgreSQL by the way.

Comment: What database are you using?  You have listed a bunch.

Comment: What if a given ID has more than one Value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select sum(avg_value)
from (select id, avg(value) as avg_value
      from t
      group by id
     ) id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select sum(value) from table group by (id, value)
```